# XSLT - Summing numbers with commas

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT 2.0 and need to add numbers in a node which can also have comma, as per suggestions in other Stackoverflow threads I tried this.

`<xsl:variable name="SimilarRecordsDebitSum1" sum(../Records[PaymentReference=$PayRef1 and ClientID=$vClientID1]/DebitAmount/number(translate(.,',',''))) />`

But when I debug it in Visual Studio, it keeps on failing with this error.

```
Expected token ')', found '('.
```

I have checked the brackets and they all seem fine, without the number and translate functions it works fine but of course doesn't add up nodes where comma is present, Not sure if it's a visual studio or it's xslt processor issue or I am doing something wrong?

**Update 1**
Sorry gave the wrong xslt statement, here's the correct one.

`<xsl:variable name="SimilarRecordsDebitSum1" select="sum(/DebitAmount/number(translate(.,',','')))" />`

and simplified version of my XML, I need to sum 'DebitAmount' elements which may or may not have a comma in it's value but I am always hitting error mentioned above when debugging xslt in visual studio.

```
<Gen>
  <Header>
    <Login>Login</Login>
  </Header>
  <Records>
    <DebitAmount>1,402.79</DebitAmount>
  </Records>
  <Records>
    <DebitAmount>10</DebitAmount>
  </Records>  
</Gen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***-- edited in view of clarifactions --***

I have managed to reproduce the error you report by using the Microsoft XslCompiledTransform engine. This is an XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support the XSLT 2.0 syntax you are using.

To solve the problem using this engine, you could rewrite your stylesheet along the lines of:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Gen">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="Records">
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(DebitAmount, ',', '')"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($amounts)/amount)"/>
    </total>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcyo/2

---

Note that some Microsoft processors may require the extension function to be in a different namespace.

Comment: Sorry Select is actually there, I copied the two pieces so missed it, I simplified the statement to this but it still throws the same error.                                                                   
                                                                                                                             
 ````<xsl:variable name="SimilarRecordsDebitSum1" select="sum(/DebitAmount/number(translate(.,',','')))" />````

Comment: Has anyone got this kind of statement working in Visual Studio debugging?

Comment: You can see a code working against your example here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcyo. Note that this requires an XSLT 2.0 processor. The error you show suggests that you are using a processor that supports only XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Visual Studio 2019, when I set the xslt version to 1.0 it doesn't even let me go into debugging but when I change it to 2.0, it starts the debugging session but then at run time throws the same error. Is there a way to change default processor Visual studio is using?

Comment: It's not a question of setting the version of the stylesheet, but using an XSLT engine that supports XSLT 2.0 syntax. I am not a user of VS and I don't know which processors it supports.